# Check HDFS disc usage over time

Tags: hdfs, ambari, hdp

We have a cluster set up with HDP, and we use it in order to execute a process that runs for ~40h, going through different tasks and stages. I would like to know what is a highest HDFS Disc Usage during this period, and at what time. I can see that Ambari Dashboard (v2.7.4.0) and NameNode UI provide current HDFS Disc Usage, but I can't find an option to show it over time (even though CPU and Memory usage have such option and nice graphs). Does anyone know is it possible to gather such statistics?

Comment: Have you checked Ambari Metrics Grafana UI ?

Comment: WIll do it now, thanks